# Retrieve a select field value to fill a form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to use a ready-made select list of all the world countries (I don't want to store it in database) to fill an input field of a Django modelform, but I don't know which way to go.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/

Enjoy!

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like it will require them to be stored in a database? He specifically said he did not want to store them in a database. The question is a bit silly, he could I suppose just dump the data into a list and make a choice field.

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just store these in a table and cache the queryset for the ModelChoiceField.

Comment: When I said that I didn't want to store data, I meant store it manually. So Brandon's application is prefect. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do that is to hardcode it into the template.

This list has it done already: 
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/376

Comment: It's exactly the list I've got. Ok, let's say I harcore it into the template: how can link it to my form or retrieve the value of the list to fill the field of my form? 
Sorry if it seems like a silly question to you guys, but I'm new in Django and I'm in a bit of a rush.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

by following this guide you can have automatic countries populated in your form field
http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt